# Order in Matrix Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I'm working on a problem and I'm a bit confused because I know order matters in matrix multiplication.  Consider the following question.

Let A be a (2x2) matrix and let
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 \\ 
1 & 4
\end{bmatrix} and\ C=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3\\ 
4 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If $A^{T}$B=C, what is A?

I assume we multiply both sides by $B^{-1}$ but in this case would the right side of the expression equal $B^{-1}$C or C$B^{-1}$?

Comment: In this case you have $A^T B  = C \implies A^T B B^{-1} = A^T I = A^T = CB^{-1} \implies A = (CB^{-1})^T$. 

It's also good to note that this works as $B$ is invertible-- if $B$ weren't invertible then we wouldn't be able to solve for $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have $BB^{-1}$ on the left hand side to produce $$A^{T}BB^{-1}$$ so you multiply the $B^{-1}$ to the right on the RHS as well
$$A^{T}BB^{-1} = CB^{-1}$$